# Cloned a repo, how to update all branches/master in new repo from original repo?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone

I cloned a repo and in my new repo I added the remote to the original repo so it looks like this:

```
origin  git@gitlab.com:MyDomain/MyCode.git (fetch) 
origin  git@gitlab.com:MyDomain/MyCode.git (push) 
original    git@gitlab.com:OldDomain/OriginalCode.git (fetch) 
original    git@hgitlab.com:OldDomain/OriginalCode.git (push)
```

We have multiple people working on the original repo and updating branches constantly. I will need to update origin with all the changes to original including its branches. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to do this is:

`git push --all origin`

This will push *tags* and *branches* to **origin**.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't update the branch from original to origin

Comment: Confirm the name of local branch is same as the branch in origin before run "git push --all origin", or git will create a new branch in origin.

Comment: What do you mean with *original*?

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge command to get commits from the branches on "original" repo

```
(suppose your workspace is on origin)
git fetch original
git merge original/BRANCHE_NAME_COMMITS_COME_FROM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for pushing every thing:

```
git push --all
git push --tags
```

To push tags you need the second line too.
Then use this in any repo to get every new thing:

```
git fetch --all
git pull -all
```